# Azure Event Hubs Premium pricing model

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, price

I am trying to understand Azure Event hubs premium pricing model.

According to docs: Price for Event Hubs Premium is €X.XXXX per hour per Premium Unit.
Premium Units are configured on Event Hubs namespace level, which can consist of multiple Event Hubs.

If I have a single namespace with PU set to 1, and I have 10 event hubs in this namespace. Am I charged for 1 PU, meaning 1 * €X.XXXX per hour? or PU is multiplied by the event hubs count in the namespace, meaning 1 * 10 * €X.XXXX per hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throughput of all your event hubs put together will be governed by the throughput at the namespace level. So in your case, a name space of 1PU will be charged at 1PU only regardless of the number of eventhubs within it.
As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#throughput-units) :

> Up to 40 throughput units can be purchased for an Event Hubs
> namespace and are **shared** across all event hubs in that namespace.